# Add a nautilus bookmark in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

According to the help text here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-bookmarks-edit.html.en

In order to add a bookmark to nautilus I need to "Click the window menu in the toolbar and pick Bookmark this Location." but I can't find the window menu. I presume the toolbar is the top bar in the window but this only gives me search, toggle view, view options, and a burger menu with a few items on it, none of which seems to have anything to do with bookmarks.

I've seen plenty of other questions similar to mine but they all apply to older versions and the UI seems completely different for every version.

Comment: Did you try drag-and-drop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to (right-)click on the name of the directory in the topbar (the one with down arrow) i.e. the final subdirectory name - in this example image (click on files).

You cannot do this on opening the first level of the drive but you can if you select a folder.

[image: click on files]